# python min function with two iterable arugments

Tags: python, dictionary, min

I understand that min will give me the smallest item if I use a list or a group of numbers

```
min([5, 10])] >>> 5
min((5, 10)) >>> 5
```

but when this was used in map:

```
L1 = [1, 28, 36]
L2 = [2, 57, 9]
for elt in map(min, L1, L2):
    print(elt)
```

it gives me back:

```
1
28
9
```

isn't map suppose to help me to apply min to L1 and L2 in turn? and I am kind of expecting:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Read the documentation for [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).  You're basically doing `map(min, zip(L1, L2))`

Comment: Add brackets around the *L1* and *L2* like this ``map(min, [L1, L2]) ``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `min` of each of several lists, you need to create a list (or iterable) of the lists to hand to map:

```
for elt in map(min, (L1, L2)):
    print(elt)
```

That has the effect of calling `min(L1)` and then `min(L2)`.

`map` can take any number of iterable arguments; it assembles all of the corresponding elements of the iterations and passes all of them to the provided function. So `map(min, L1, L2)` is similar to `(min(L1[0], L2[0]), min(L1[1], L2[1]), min(L1[2], L2[2]))` (except that it is an iterable, not a tuple).

Comment: Basically, as @PatrickHaugh said, it's as if his code is `map(min, zip(L1, L2))`.

Comment: got it!! Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianDean: In this case, it is; that's not generally the case, though. It works because `min` happens to either compute the minimum of a single iterable (if given one argument) or the minimum of all its arguments (if given more than one argument).

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are

```
L1 = [1, 28, 36]
L2 = [2, 57, 9]
```

then

```
map(min, L1, L2)
```

will apply the `min()` function to the *corresponding elements* of `L1`, `L2`:

```
min( 1,  2)       # result:  1
min(28, 57)       # result: 28
min(36,  9)       # result:  9
```

(But it will do it only if there is a *request* for evaluating it (so called a *lazy evaluation*) - as the `for` loop in your case - so it will not return a *list* `[1, 28, 9]`, but a *`map`* object.

The `map` object is a sort of the *iterator* - something as a *recipe how to do it*.

Why? Because *lists* may be *very very long*, but the recipe is still the same - the *short* one.)

Comment: You are right - it is *like* the `zip()` built-in function, but it *doesn't perform `zip()`* as a temporary result (yielding pairs) but it directly yields the *return values of the mapped function*.